# Loop only through specific array

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
$array = array("Farbe" => array("blau", "rot", "grün"),
               "Größe" => array("klein", "mittel", "groß"));
```

The order is random, so "Farbe" could be the first array but "Größe" could also be the first array.

In my foreach i want only the array with "Farbe". How can i tell my foreach to only loop through the "Farbe" array?

Comment: `foreach($array['Farbe'] as $val)`. That's kinda basic stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways depending on what you want to do.

```
foreach($array['Farbe'] as $key){
    //code goes here
}
```

If you needed to do something with that data in your html like adding it to a table you could do something like this.

```
<table>
<?php foreach($array['Farbe'] as $key):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access by key to the array and then loop it:

```
foreach($array['Farbe'] as $farbe) {
    //Do something with $farbe.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$farbeArray = $array['Farbe'];
foreach($farbeArray as $value){
    echo $value;
}
```